# Deleting a specific word form a text file in python

Tags: python

I used this code to delete a word from a text file.

```
f = open('./test.txt','r')
a = ['word1','word2','word3']
lst = []
for line in f:
    for word in a:
        if word in line:
            line = line.replace(word,'')
    lst.append(line)
f.close()
f = open('./test.txt','w')
for line in lst:
    f.write(line)
f.close()
```

But for some reason if the words have the same characters, all those characters get deleted. So for e.g 
in my code:

```
def cancel():
    global refID
    f1=open("refID.txt","r")
    line=f1.readline()
    flag = 0
    while flag==0:
        refID=input("Enter the reference ID or type 'q' to quit: ")
        for i in line.split(','):
            if refID == i:
                flag=1
        if flag ==1:
            print("reference ID found")
            cancelsub()
        elif (len(refID))<1:
            print("Reference ID not found, please re-enter your reference ID\n")
            cancel()
        elif refID=="q":
            flag=1
        else:
            print("reference ID not found\n")
            menu()

def cancelsub():
    global refIDarr, index
    refIDarr=[]
    index=0
    f = open('flightbooking.csv')
    csv_f = csv.reader(f)
    for row in csv_f:
        refIDarr.append(row[1])
    for i in range (len(refIDarr)):
        if refID==refIDarr[i]:
            index=i
            print(index)
    while True:
        proceed=input("You are about to cancel your flight booking, are you sure you would like to proceed? y/n?: ")
        while proceed>"y" or proceed<"n" or (proceed>"n" and proceed<"y") :
            proceed=input("Invalid entry. \nPlease enter y or n: ")
        if proceed=="y":
            Continue()
            break
        elif proceed=="n":
            main_menu
            break    
            exit
        break


def Continue():
    lines = list()
    with open('flightbooking.csv', 'r') as readFile:
        reader = csv.reader(readFile)
        for row in reader:
            lines.append(row)
            for field in row:
                if field ==refID:
                    lines.remove(row)
                    break
    with open('flightbooking.csv', 'w') as writeFile:
            writer = csv.writer(writeFile)
            writer.writerows(lines)
            f = open('refID.txt','r')
            a=refIDarr[index]  
            print(a)
            lst = []
            for line in f:
                for word in a:
                    if word in line:
                        line = line.replace(word,'')
                lst.append(line)
                print(lst)
            f.close()
            f = open('refID.txt','w')
            for line in lst:
                f.write(line)
            f.close()
            print("Booking successfully cancelled")
            menu()
```

When the code is run, the refID variable has one word stored in it, and it should replace just that word with a blank space, but it takes that word for e.g 'AB123', finds all other words which might have an 'A' or a 'B' or the numbers, and replace all of them. How do I make it so it only deletes the word?

Text file before running code:
AD123,AB123
Expected Output in the text file:
AD123,
Output in text file:
D,
Edit: I have added the entire code, and maybe you can help now after seeing that the array is being appended to and then being used to delete from a text file.

Comment: a is a string, by doing for word in a - you are iterating over the string character by character

Comment: Please edit the question to show an example input line (or two), output and expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here's my opinion.

refIDarr = ["AB123"]

`a = refIDarr[0] => a = "AB123"`

strings in python are iterable, so when you do for word in a, you're getting 5 loops where each word is actually a letter.

Something like the following is being executed.

```
if "A" in line:
    line = line.replace("A","")
if "B" in line:
    line = line.replace("B","")
if "1" in line:
    line = line.replace("1","")
if "2" in line:
    line = line.replace("2","")
if "3" in line:
    line = line.replace("3","")
```

they correct way to do this is loop over `refIDarr`

```
for word in refIDarr:
    line = line.replace(word,'')
```

*NOTE*: You don't need the if statement, since if the word is not in the line it will return the same line as it was.

`"abc".replace("bananan", "") => "abc"`

Here's a working example:

```
refIDarr = ["hello", "world", "lol"]

with open('mytext.txt', "r") as f:
    data = f.readlines()
    for word in refIDarr:
        data = [line.replace(word, "") for line in data]

with open("mytext.txt", "w") as newf:
    newf.writelines(data)
```

Comment: I tried doing this, but It's just deleting everything from the text file now, I want it to replace the word in the list with a blank space

Comment: Still doesn't work for me, It still does the same thing, If you can look at the code, I edited it so you can see the entire thing

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:
`a=refIDarr[index]`

If `refIDarr` is a list of words, accessing specific index makes `a` be a word. Later, when you iterate over `a` (`for word in a:`), `word` becomes a letter and not a word as you expect, which causes eventually replacing characters of word instead the word itself in your file.

To avoid that, remove `a=refIDarr[index]` and change your loop to be:

```
for line in f:
    for word in refIDarr:
        if word in line:
            line = line.replace(word,'')
```

Comment: I tried your method, and now its deleting every form of text from the text file. I want it to remove only the specific word in the list

Comment: my solution assumes that `refIDarr` is a list, ie `refIDarr=["word_to_replace"]`.Is it the same in your code?

Comment: refIDarr is a list indeed, but it has multiple strings stored inside, thats why I was calling refIDarr[index] so that specific word is replaced, but whats getting replaced are the letters. I even assigned refIDarr[index] to another variable and did for word in new_variable, but it still didn't work.